# Apache2 is not starting,I am using Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: linux, apache2, ubuntu-16.04

**Unable to start Apache2 server after I modifed dir.conf file, even after changing it back to normal**

*I modified /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/dir.conf and changed the order and wrote index.php in
the first place before index.html, so the file contents have been modified from
"DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm" to now
"DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.cgi index.pl index.xhtml index.htm". But still
changing that back to original order, also does not start apache2 server, it gives the same
error. I tried restarting and stop and start, but none seem to work.*

```
** Here are the details of systemctl status apache2.service **

● apache2.service - LSB: Apache2 web server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/init.d/apache2; bad; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /lib/systemd/system/apache2.service.d
           └─apache2-systemd.conf
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2020-11-24 12:28:31 IST; 5min ago
     Docs: man:systemd-sysv-generator(8)
  Process: 20300 ExecStop=/etc/init.d/apache2 stop (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 25755 ExecStart=/etc/init.d/apache2 start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]:  *
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]:  * The apache2 configtest failed.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]: Output of config test was:
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]: AH00534: apache2: Configuration error: More than one MPM loaded.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]: Action 'configtest' failed.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost apache2[25755]: The Apache error log may have more information.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start LSB: Apache2 web server.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 24 12:28:31 localhost systemd[1]: apache2.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

```
**Here is the details of journalctl -xe**

Nov 24 12:44:42 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:75]
Nov 24 12:44:42 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:77]
Nov 24 12:44:43 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:75]
Nov 24 12:44:43 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:77]
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: Failed to start MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has failed
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has failed.
-- 
-- The result is failed.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Unit entered failed state.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:75]
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: Stopped MySQL Community Server.
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has finished shutting down.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: Starting MySQL Community Server...
-- Subject: Unit mysql.service has begun start-up
-- Defined-By: systemd
-- Support: http://lists.freedesktop.org/mailman/listinfo/systemd-devel
-- 
-- Unit mysql.service has begun starting up.
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.545855Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: max_open_files: 1024 (requested 5000)
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.545908Z 0 [Warning] Changed limits: table_open_cache: 431 (requested 2000)
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.705792Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --expl
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.707018Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 5.7.32-0ubuntu0.16.04.1) starting as process 538
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.709650Z 0 [ERROR] Could not open file '/var/log/mysql/error.log' for error logging: No suc
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.709678Z 0 [ERROR] Aborting
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.709703Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost mysqld[5387]: 2020-11-24T07:14:44.709770Z 0 [Note] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost systemd[1]: mysql.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:77]
Nov 24 12:44:44 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:75]
Nov 24 12:44:45 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:77]
Nov 24 12:44:45 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:75]
Nov 24 12:44:45 localhost kernel: [drm:drm_mode_addfb2 [drm]] [FB:77]
```